# Optaplanner vehicle routing problem with time window and dynamic departure time

Tags: optaplanner

I'm working on a VRPTW where I need to optimize when a truck should leave the depot, considering also an hourly dispatching limit. In other words, the departure time is not fixed, while what is known is the time of the day when vehicles can start to be dispatched and how many can be sent out each hour.

Is there a way to model the domain so that I can achieve this goal? My current implementation of the VRPTW is working but doesn't optimize the departure time, this results in having many trucks leaving too early and, while it meets the delivery window of the order, there's room of improvement by spreading the departure time across the day

Answer (score 0):

1. Take the [Timefold](https://timefold.ai/) VRPTW example from timefold-quickstarts (that's a new quickstart since we [continued](https://timefold.ai/blog/2023/optaplanner-fork) OptaPlanner. It uses Timefold Solver Community, so open source too)
2. Play with the ArrivalTimeUpdatingVariableListener to delay some trucks.
3. Make sure the listener is a 100% deterministic, regardless of who got moved in
   the timeblock last. Typically ID sorting works well. For example,
   for 3 trucks an hour, given `A, C, E` there already there, adding
   `B` would result in `A, B, C` and trigger `E` to pushed to the next time block.
4. Make sure the listener is recursive towards future time. In the example above, when `E` gets pushed to the next timeblock which already contains `D, G, H`, it would result in `D, E, G` and trigger pushing `H` one down too.

---

Alternatively, if and only if all your vehicles are exactly the same, just create enough vehicles to fill every starting block and use the Timefold VRPTW quickstart out of the box.

Then add a hard constraint to limit the total **used** vehicles.

Comment: While I think this approach will work quite well with an homogeneous fleet, I'm afraid it will introduce some bias into the system with an heterogeneous fleet. In fact this will force a class of vehicles to start on a specific time slot, which might not be optimal (as some vehicles can only take certain orders etc).

The way I (partially) tackled this is to calculate the departure time of the vehicle based on the first order. While it "works", it doesn't respect the hourly limit and there are some spikes as it uses the projected time window (start) to calculate the vehicle's departure time

Comment: My approach is also not optimal since if I run it twice I often get a different result because, as said, the departure time is dynamic based on the orders assigned to that vehicle. 

I played quite a lot with movers, which I could't make it work (most probably due to my limited knowledge). Another way I explored is to set the departure time as PlanningVariable and provide a range of allowed values as ValueRangeProvider. The problem is that I can't mix PlanningListVariable with PlanningVariable together

Comment: I agree, a heterogeneous fleet makes this an interesting challenge to model. Neither of my proposals are ideal. Not a model to figure out in a quick SO question I fear.